# aform types in Yesod

Tags: forms, haskell, yesod

I've been following [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0WY0KWCraxI) for learning Yesod, and am trying to run this simple form:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies               #-}
{-# LANGUAGE QuasiQuotes                #-}
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses      #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell            #-}
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings          #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ViewPatterns               #-} 
import Control.Applicative((<$>),(<*>))
import Yesod

data App = App

mkYesod "App" [parseRoutes|
/accum Accum GET
|]

instance Yesod App

instance RenderMessage App FormMessage where
   renderMessage _ _ = defaultFormMessage

data Info = Info 
   { deposit :: Double
   , rate    :: Double
   , years   :: Double
   }

aform :: AForm App App Info
aform = Info
   <$> areq doubleField "Deposit" Nothing
   <*> areq doubleField "Rate" Nothing
   <*> areq doubleField "Years" Nothing

accum x = deposit x * (1 + rate x * years x)

mform = renderTable aform

getAccum :: Handler RepHtml
getAccum = do
   ((result, widget), enc) <- runFormGet mform
   case result of
      FormSuccess info -> defaultLayout [whamlet|<p> #{show (accum info)} |]
      _                -> defaultLayout [whamlet| 
      <form method=get action=@{Accum} enctype=#{enc}>
         <table>
            ^{widget}
         <input type=submit>
         |]

main = warpDebug 2012 App
```

When I `runhaskell forms.hs`, I get this error:

```
forms.hs:27:10:
    ‘AForm’ is applied to too many type arguments
    In the type signature for ‘aform’: aform :: AForm App App Info
```

After futzing with a number of variations of the type signature, I kept getting errors.  The ghci `:info AForm` reads

```
Prelude Yesod> :info AForm
type role AForm nominal nominal
newtype AForm (m :: * -> *) a
```

But a change to `aform :: AForm (App -> App) Info` gives me this error:

```
forms.hs:27:17:
    The first argument of ‘AForm’ should have kind ‘* -> *’,
      but ‘App -> App’ has kind ‘*’
```

Any ideas on how to resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type signature for `areq` is:

```
areq :: (RenderMessage site FormMessage, HandlerSite m ~ site, MonadHandler m) => Field m a -> FieldSettings site -> Maybe a -> AForm m a
```

Note how it takes two parameters, and the first parameter is an instance of `MonadHandler`. Therefore, your signature on `aform` will need to have the same parameter. In your code, this may look like:

```
aform :: AForm (HandlerT App IO) Info
```

or the shortened form:

```
aform :: AForm Handler Info
```

Have a look at [the car example in the Yesod book](http://www.yesodweb.com/book/forms#forms_create_literal_aform_literal_s).